# Javac error when launching appcelerator with genymotion

Tags: java, android, virtualbox, appcelerator, genymotion

I have installed Appcelerator, genymotion and virtualbox to program some android application, I open genymotion and I emulate the android system but when I want to run an app with appcelerator when compiling, it send the following error.

```
[ERROR] :  Failed to compile Java source files:
[ERROR] :  
[ERROR] :  javac: file not found: C:\Users\Emilio\Desktop\U\5TO SEMESTRE\OPT Desarrollo aplicaciones móviles\Proyectos\prueba\build\android\gen\android\support\v7\appcompat\R.java
[ERROR] :  Usage: javac <options> <source files>
[ERROR] :  use -help for a list of possible options
```

I installed java SDK and JRE but it did not work either ...

The complete appcelerator log is this

```
Appcelerator Command-Line Interface, version 6.1.0
Copyright (c) 2014-2017, Appcelerator, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
2017-04-13T17:06:44.420Z | TRACE  | set environment to {"registry":"https://software.appcelerator.com","security":"https://security.appcelerator.com","baseurl":"https://platform.appcelerator.com"}
2017-04-13T17:06:44.422Z | TRACE  | checking credentials for existing session
2017-04-13T17:06:44.942Z | TRACE  | Attempting to load session info from config file
2017-04-13T17:06:44.953Z | TRACE  | check if session is invalidated
2017-04-13T17:06:45.891Z | TRACE  | registry result 200 application/json undefined undefined false undefined
2017-04-13T17:06:45.904Z | TRACE  | registry returned { expiry: 1492707991013 }
2017-04-13T17:06:45.905Z | TRACE  | refresh session expiry to:  1492707991013
2017-04-13T17:06:45.907Z | TRACE  | session expiry 1492707991013 false
2017-04-13T17:06:45.908Z | TRACE  | Arrow Cloud config file: C:\Users\Emilio\.acs
2017-04-13T17:06:45.909Z | TRACE  | found Arrow Cloud login { mid: '3d0a7a3fd1d9a522d5ee47a037eac917f508f7b8',
  publishPort: 443,
  publishHost: 'https://admin.cloudapp-enterprise.appcelerator.com',
  username: 'emiliosk8.-@live.cl',
  cookie: [ 'connect.sid=s%3A7rWBWFm8yledpnM3TCi9waqb.nmeJ%2FD5WU6RW%2Fv28ElZlh%2B0tbbI%2BB90aqCwgrVIyCmA; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 27 Apr 2017 16:30:09 GMT; HttpOnly' ],
  defaultEP: 
   { publishHost: 'https://admin.cloudapp-enterprise.appcelerator.com',
     publishPort: 443 } } , checking nodeACSEndpoint= https://admin.cloudapp-enterprise.appcelerator.com
2017-04-13T17:06:45.910Z | TRACE  | Arrow Cloud cookie expiry [ 1493310609000 ]
2017-04-13T17:06:45.911Z | TRACE  | session already loaded in opts.session
2017-04-13T17:06:45.912Z | TRACE  | getCredentials() session:
{
  "ipaddress": "192.168.0.8",
  "username": "emiliosk8.-@live.cl",
  "password": "<OMITTED>",
  "session": "<OMITTED>",
  "nonce": "<OMITTED>",
  "environment": {
    "name": "production",
    "isProduction": true,
    "acsBaseUrl": "https://api.cloud.appcelerator.com",
    "acsAuthBaseUrl": "https://secure-identity.cloud.appcelerator.com",
    "nodeACSEndpoint": "https://admin.cloudapp-enterprise.appcelerator.com"
  },
  "token": "<OMITTED>",
  "fingerprint": "3d0a7a3fd1d9a522d5ee47a037eac917f508f7b8",
  "fingerprint_description": "Windows Machine ID: 1cc4aaba-6339-4dd8-b048-21c002f5e533",
  "org_id": 990806121146306,
  "expiry": 1492707991013
}
2017-04-13T17:06:45.912Z | TRACE  | loading plugins for command "run"
2017-04-13T17:06:46.223Z | TRACE  | run search paths:
[
  "C:\\Users\\Emilio\\.appcelerator\\install\\6.1.0\\package",
  "C:\\Users\\Emilio\\.appcelerator\\install\\6.1.0\\package\\node_modules",
  "C:\\Users\\Emilio\\Desktop\\node_modules",
  "C:\\Users\\Emilio\\node_modules",
  "C:\\Users\\node_modules",
  "C:\\node_modules",
  "C:\\Users\\Emilio\\.appcelerator\\.npm\\lib\\node_modules"
]
2017-04-13T17:06:46.225Z | DEBUG  | [PLUGIN-LOAD] 0ms C:\Users\Emilio\.appcelerator\install\6.1.0\package\appc.js
2017-04-13T17:06:48.948Z | DEBUG  | [PLUGIN-LOAD] 2678ms C:\Users\Emilio\.appcelerator\install\6.1.0\package\node_modules\appc-cli-titanium\appc.js
2017-04-13T17:06:48.948Z | DEBUG  | run plugin: C:\Users\Emilio\.appcelerator\install\6.1.0\package\node_modules\appc-cli-titanium
2017-04-13T17:06:49.000Z | DEBUG  | [PLUGIN-LOAD] 20ms C:\Users\Emilio\.appcelerator\install\6.1.0\package\node_modules\arrow\appc.js
2017-04-13T17:06:49.020Z | DEBUG  | run plugin: C:\Users\Emilio\.appcelerator\install\6.1.0\package\node_modules\arrow
2017-04-13T17:06:49.029Z | TRACE  | plugin "arrow" failed its "when" function check, skipping...
2017-04-13T17:06:49.030Z | TRACE  | loading plugin "titanium" for command "run" CLI options via function
2017-04-13T17:06:49.044Z | TRACE  | loading plugin "titanium" for command "run" CLI options via array
2017-04-13T17:06:49.046Z | TRACE  | executing command "run" with the following plugins:
["titanium"]
2017-04-13T17:06:49.087Z | TRACE  | Attempting to load session info from config file
2017-04-13T17:06:49.094Z | TRACE  | check if session is invalidated
2017-04-13T17:06:49.886Z | TRACE  | registry result 200 application/json undefined undefined false undefined
2017-04-13T17:06:49.886Z | TRACE  | registry returned { expiry: 1492707995013 }
2017-04-13T17:06:49.886Z | TRACE  | refresh session expiry to:  1492707995013
2017-04-13T17:06:49.887Z | TRACE  | session expiry 1492707995013 false
2017-04-13T17:06:49.888Z | TRACE  | session already loaded in opts.session
2017-04-13T17:06:49.890Z | DEBUG  | Titanium Downloads Last Checked: 1492101153718
2017-04-13T17:06:50.040Z | TRACE  | No project alloy hook; skipping update to 1.0.0
2017-04-13 14:07:05
Operating System
  Name                        = Microsoft Windows 7 Ultimate
  Version                     = 6.1.7601
  Architecture                = 32bit
  # CPUs                      = 8
  Memory                      = 8491417600
Node.js
  Node.js Version             = 4.6.0
  npm Version                 = 2.15.9
Titanium CLI
  CLI Version                 = 5.0.11
Titanium SDK
  SDK Version                 = 6.0.3.GA
  SDK Path                    = C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\6.0.3.GA
  Target Platform             = android
Command
  C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\Emilio\.appcelerator\install\6.1.0\package\node_modules\titanium\lib\titanium.js build run --platform android --log-level trace --sdk 6.0.3.GA --project-dir C:\Users\Emilio\Desktop\U\5TO SEMESTRE\OPT Desarrollo aplicaciones móviles\Proyectos\prueba --target device --android-sdk C:\android-sdk-win --device-id 192.168.186.101:5555 --no-colors --no-progress-bars --no-prompt --prompt-type socket-bundle --prompt-port 49230 --config-file C:\Users\Emilio\AppData\Local\Temp\build-1492103209888.json --no-banner --project-dir C:\Users\Emilio\Desktop\U\5TO SEMESTRE\OPT Desarrollo aplicaciones móviles\Proyectos\prueba
[INFO] :   Found Titanium module id=hyperloop version=2.0.1 platform=android deploy-type=test path=C:\ProgramData\Application Data\Titanium\modules\android\hyperloop\2.0.1
[INFO] :   Found Titanium module id=ti.cloud version=3.2.11 platform=commonjs deploy-type=test path=C:\ProgramData\Application Data\Titanium\modules\commonjs\ti.cloud\3.2.11
[INFO] :   Found Titanium plugin id=hyperloop version=latest 
[INFO] :   Deploy type: test
[INFO] :   Building for target: device
[INFO] :   Building for device: 192.168.186.101:5555
[INFO] :   Targeting Android SDK API: 23
[INFO] :   Building for the following architectures: armeabi-v7a, x86
[INFO] :   Signing with keystore: C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\6.0.3.GA\android\dev_keystore (tidev)
[INFO] :   Debugging disabled
[INFO] :   Profiler disabled
[INFO] :   Forcing rebuild: C:\Users\Emilio\Desktop\U\5TO SEMESTRE\OPT Desarrollo aplicaciones móviles\Proyectos\prueba\build\android\build-manifest.json does not exist
[INFO] :   Starting Hyperloop assembly
[INFO] :   [Hyperloop] Using system metabase cache file at C:\Users\Emilio\AppData\Local\Temp\hyperloop_android-23_metabase.c5b34c57144cd3138bade358605e1b6b4d0d5495.json.gz
[INFO] :   Skipping Hyperloop compile, no usage found ...
[INFO] :   Finished Hyperloop assembly
[INFO] :   JavaScript files need to be encrypted
[WARN] :   Overwriting file C:\Users\Emilio\Desktop\U\5TO SEMESTRE\OPT Desarrollo aplicaciones móviles\Proyectos\prueba\build\android\bin\assets\Resources\assets\images\tab1.png
[WARN] :   Overwriting file C:\Users\Emilio\Desktop\U\5TO SEMESTRE\OPT Desarrollo aplicaciones móviles\Proyectos\prueba\build\android\bin\assets\Resources\assets\images\tab1@2x.png
[WARN] :   Overwriting file C:\Users\Emilio\Desktop\U\5TO SEMESTRE\OPT Desarrollo aplicaciones móviles\Proyectos\prueba\build\android\bin\assets\Resources\assets\images\tab1@3x.png
[WARN] :   Overwriting file C:\Users\Emilio\Desktop\U\5TO SEMESTRE\OPT Desarrollo aplicaciones móviles\Proyectos\prueba\build\android\bin\assets\Resources\assets\images\tab2.png
[WARN] :   Overwriting file C:\Users\Emilio\Desktop\U\5TO SEMESTRE\OPT Desarrollo aplicaciones móviles\Proyectos\prueba\build\android\bin\assets\Resources\assets\images\tab2@2x.png
[WARN] :   Overwriting file C:\Users\Emilio\Desktop\U\5TO SEMESTRE\OPT Desarrollo aplicaciones móviles\Proyectos\prueba\build\android\bin\assets\Resources\assets\images\tab2@3x.png
[WARN] :   Overwriting file C:\Users\Emilio\Desktop\U\5TO SEMESTRE\OPT Desarrollo aplicaciones móviles\Proyectos\prueba\build\android\bin\assets\Resources\appicon.png
[WARN] :   Overwriting file C:\Users\Emilio\Desktop\U\5TO SEMESTRE\OPT Desarrollo aplicaciones móviles\Proyectos\prueba\build\android\bin\assets\Resources\ti.cloud\package.json
[INFO] :   Processing JavaScript files
[INFO] :   Encrypting JavaScript files: C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\6.0.3.GA\android\titanium_prep.win32.exe "com.prueba.app" "C:\Users\Emilio\Desktop\U\5TO SEMESTRE\OPT Desarrollo aplicaciones móviles\Proyectos\prueba\build\android\assets" "app.js" "ti.cloud/ti.cloud.js" "_app_props_.json"
[INFO] :   Writing C:\Users\Emilio\Desktop\U\5TO SEMESTRE\OPT Desarrollo aplicaciones móviles\Proyectos\prueba\build\android\bin\assets\app.json
[INFO] :   Extracting module resources: C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\6.0.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-analytics.res.zip
[INFO] :   Extracting module resources: C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\6.0.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-android.res.zip
[INFO] :   Extracting module resources: C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\6.0.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-filesystem.res.zip
[INFO] :   Extracting module resources: C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\6.0.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-app.res.zip
[INFO] :   Extracting module resources: C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\6.0.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-media.res.zip
[INFO] :   Extracting module resources: C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\6.0.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-locale.res.zip
[INFO] :   Extracting module resources: C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\6.0.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-network.res.zip
[INFO] :   Extracting module resources: C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\6.0.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-xml.res.zip
[INFO] :   Extracting module resources: C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\6.0.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-platform.res.zip
[INFO] :   No aidl files to compile, continuing
[INFO] :   Generating i18n files
[INFO] :   Generating C:\Users\Emilio\Desktop\U\5TO SEMESTRE\OPT Desarrollo aplicaciones móviles\Proyectos\prueba\build\android\res\values\theme.xml
[INFO] :   Packaging application: C:\android-sdk-win\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe "package" "-f" "-m" "-J" "C:\Users\Emilio\Desktop\U\5TO SEMESTRE\OPT Desarrollo aplicaciones móviles\Proyectos\prueba\build\android\gen" "-M" "C:\Users\Emilio\Desktop\U\5TO SEMESTRE\OPT Desarrollo aplicaciones móviles\Proyectos\prueba\build\android\AndroidManifest.xml" "-A" "C:\Users\Emilio\Desktop\U\5TO SEMESTRE\OPT Desarrollo aplicaciones móviles\Proyectos\prueba\build\android\bin\assets" "-S" "C:\Users\Emilio\Desktop\U\5TO SEMESTRE\OPT Desarrollo aplicaciones móviles\Proyectos\prueba\build\android\res" "-I" "C:\android-sdk-win\platforms\android-23\android.jar" "-F" "C:\Users\Emilio\Desktop\U\5TO SEMESTRE\OPT Desarrollo aplicaciones móviles\Proyectos\prueba\build\android\bin\app.ap_" "--auto-add-overlay" "--extra-packages" "ti.modules.titanium.ui:android.support.v7.appcompat:android.support.v7.cardview" "-S" "C:\Users\Emilio\AppData\Local\Temp\117313-7872-1ma6wg3/res" "-S" "C:\Users\Emilio\AppData\Local\Temp\117313-7872-gxv5mv/res" "-S" "C:\Users\Emilio\AppData\Local\Temp\117313-7872-kh92t6/res"
[INFO] :   Building Java source files: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin\javac.exe "-J-Xmx1024M" "-encoding" "utf8" "-bootclasspath" "C:\android-sdk-win\platforms\android-23\android.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\6.0.3.GA\android\kroll-v8.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\6.0.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-analytics.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\6.0.3.GA\android\aps-analytics.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\6.0.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-android.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\6.0.3.GA\android\jaxen-1.1.1.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\6.0.3.GA\android\ti-commons-codec-1.3.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\6.0.3.GA\android\kroll-common.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\6.0.3.GA\android\titanium.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\6.0.3.GA\android\android-support-multidex.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\6.0.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-filesystem.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\6.0.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-app.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\6.0.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-ui.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\6.0.3.GA\android\nineoldandroids-appc-2.4.0.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\6.0.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-media.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\6.0.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-appcompat.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\6.0.3.GA\android\android-support-v4.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\6.0.3.GA\android\android-support-v7-appcompat.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\6.0.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-cardview.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\6.0.3.GA\android\cardview-v7-23.0.1.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\6.0.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-locale.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\6.0.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-network.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\6.0.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-xml.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\6.0.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-platform.jar;C:\ProgramData\Application Data\Titanium\modules\android\hyperloop\2.0.1\hyperloop-android.jar;C:\ProgramData\Application Data\Titanium\modules\android\hyperloop\2.0.1\lib\dexmaker-1.4.jar;C:\ProgramData\Application Data\Titanium\modules\android\hyperloop\2.0.1\lib\dexmaker-dx-1.4.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\6.0.3.GA\android\kroll-apt.jar;C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\6.0.3.GA\android\lib\titanium-verify.jar;R.class;AssetCryptImpl.class;PruebaActivity.class;PruebaAppInfo.class;PruebaApplication.class" "-d" "C:\Users\Emilio\Desktop\U\5TO SEMESTRE\OPT Desarrollo aplicaciones móviles\Proyectos\prueba\build\android\bin\classes" "-proc:none" "-target" "1.6" "-source" "1.6" "@C:\Users\Emilio\Desktop\U\5TO SEMESTRE\OPT Desarrollo aplicaciones móviles\Proyectos\prueba\build\android\java-sources.txt"
[ERROR] :  Failed to compile Java source files:
[ERROR] :  
[ERROR] :  javac: file not found: C:\Users\Emilio\Desktop\U\5TO SEMESTRE\OPT Desarrollo aplicaciones móviles\Proyectos\prueba\build\android\gen\android\support\v7\appcompat\R.java
[ERROR] :  Usage: javac <options> <source files>
[ERROR] :  use -help for a list of possible options
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your javac and java is getting using this command

- java -version
- javac -version

Also, update your java version to JDK 8

- http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Installing_Oracle_JDK-section-29004850_InstallingOracleJDK-Windows

Then run the following command via the admin command prompt

- npm install -g appcelerator
- appc use latest
- appc config set proxyServer null
- appc setup

You can check out this blog link:

- http://titaniumsolution.blogspot.com/2016/12/fresh-installation-appcelerator-studio.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: java version 1.8.0_121
Java SE run time  enviroment 1.8.0_121
Java hostpot 25.121
javac 1.8.0_121
also I updated sdk and jre but it didnt work :/
I also ran those commands, but it did not work :(

Comment: help please u.u